# Google drive API URL changes

Tags: java, google-drive-api

The application is running on production server which access `https://www.googleapi.com` through a proxy server. So how to set the url instead of `https://www.googleapi.com` to `http://www.googleapi.com:443`.

The sample code what currently is being used is

```
    File dataStoreDir = new File(resourceDir, credentials);

    JsonFactory jacksonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    //List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("http://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive:443");

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(dataStoreDir);


    String clientSecret = config.getClientSecret();

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(resourceDir, clientSecret));
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jacksonFactory, new InputStreamReader(in));


    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    httpTransport, jacksonFactory, clientSecrets, scopes)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .setAuthorizationServerEncodedUrl("http://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive:443")
                    .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

    logger.info("Credentials saved to " + dataStoreDir.getAbsolutePath());


    drive =  new Drive.Builder(
            httpTransport, jacksonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName(applicationName)
            .build();
```

How to change the url in above code?
When I change the `drive` instance creation

```
drive =  new Drive.Builder(
                httpTransport, jacksonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(applicationName).setRootUrl("http://www.googleapis.com:443/")
                .build();
```

Then it gives the error

```
    ERROR [2016-05-03 18:39:10,847] com.test.intranet.sao.GoogleDocSAO: Connection reset
! java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
! at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:675) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
! at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37) ~[google-http-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
! at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94) ~[google-http-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
! at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972) ~[google-http-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
! at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419) ~[google-api-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
! at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352) ~[google-api-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
! at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469) ~[google-api-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Google drive can work through a proxy server by applying the required connections to the following hosts and ports as listed in [Google Drive firewall and proxy setting](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2589954?hl=en&rd=1).

However, please note that Google does not currently support authentication for connections to their addresses. You must bypass authentication for the given addresses in Google Apps Administrator Help page to allow Google to work through your proxy.

Possible proxy server configurations are given in [How to configure your proxy server to work with Google Drive](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/120790.aspx).